# Is Dispose() necessary before recreating a large bitmap inside a loop?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the code:

```
void Method1() {
    Bitmap bitmap1;
    foreach (string name in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames) {
        bitmap1 = new Bitmap(name);
        ... // process bitmap
        bitmap1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is Dispose() necessary inside the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net and Bitmap not automatically disposed by GC when there is no memory left](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5838632/448144) The marked answer should explain why you need to dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah. That bitmap object is holding a memory map open on the file!

Better method as this code structure can use `using`:

```
void Method1() {
    foreach (string name in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames) {
        using (var bitmap1 = new Bitmap(name))
        {
            ... // process bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `using` seems to be already covered in the linked duplicate too ► http://stackoverflow.com/a/5838649/448144

Comment: Why declare bitmap1 with `var` and not with `Bitmap`?

Comment: @PauloBarretto: I always use var when assigning at decl time. The typesystem will infer the correct type every time.